# Plotting a table in R

Tags: r

I want to plot a table of my data frame with lines and color formatting.  So far the only solution I have come up with is through packages `xtables` and `data.table` but I seem to get the output in Latex code.

1. How do I output this code in R to see what it looks like?
2. Is there no simple solution for plotting a table with the base package?

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use plot function. 
For example data set `iris`, which is available in R by default.
There are 5 columns there.

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

You can plot it using

`plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)`

Comment: Thanks my question was poorly worded, how do you make this output with an outline and column lines?

Comment: just write in console `print(iris)` or just `iris`

Comment: this doesn't produce any lines on the column and rows

Comment: write `head(iris)` it will show you print just for the beginning of the document. In fact `print` does the same, but for all dataset and your headers are somewhere on top.